# VBA to Java convert the loops

Tags: java, vba

Here is the original vba code:

```vb
For i = 0 To M
     St(i) = i * dS '  
     C(N, i) = Max(0, z * (St(i) - X))  
Next
For j = N - 1 To 0 Step -1
    For i = 1 To M - 1
    pu = 0.5 * (v ^ 2 * i ^ 2 + b * i) * dt
    pm = 1 - v ^ 2 * i ^ 2 * dt
    pd = 0.5 * (v ^ 2 * i ^ 2 - b * i) * dt

    C(j, i) = Df * (pu * C(j + 1, i + 1) + pm * C(j + 1, i) + pd * C(j + 1, i - 1))
    If AmeEurFlag = "a" Then
        C(j, i) = Max(z * (St(i) - X), C(j, i))
    End If
    Next
    If z = 1 Then  
        C(j, 0) = 0
        C(j, M) = (St(i) - X)
    Else
        C(j, 0) = X
        C(j, M) = 0
    End If
Next
```

and I want to convert to java here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < M; i++) 
{
    St[i] = i * dS;
    C[(int) N][i] = Math.max(0, z * (St[i] - X)); 
}


for (int j = (int) (N - 1); j < 0; j--) 
{
    for (int i = 1; i < M-1; i++) 
    {
        pu = 0.5 * (Math.pow(v, 2) * Math.pow(i, 2)+ b * i) * dt;
        pm = 1 - Math.pow(v, 2) * Math.pow(i, 2)* dt;
        pd = 0.5 * (Math.pow(v, 2)* (Math.pow(i, 2) - b * i) * dt);

        C[j] [i] = Df * (pu * C[j + 1] [i + 1] + pm * C[j + 1] [i] + pd * C[j + 1] [i - 1]);
        if (AmeEurFlag == "a" ) 
        {
            C[j] [i] = Math.max(z * (St[i] - X), C[j][i]);

        }
        }

    if (z == 1) 
    {
        C[j][0] = 0;
        C[j][M] = (St[i] - X);
    }           
    else
    {
        C[j][0] = X;
        C[j][M] = 0;

    }
}
```

I have an error in this line 
    C[j][M] = (St[i] - X);
Because there no "i" variable. I'm out of first loop. So eclipse says that you should create a variable. In vba I can create a variable beginning of the code like: "Dim i As Integer" but in java is it possible? How can I solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: what `i` refer to ?? it's the loop ?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic Java syntax as covered in any tutorial.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure but in VBA code it is used only in loops and created beginning of the code. "Maybe Dim i As Integer" gives a default value like 0?

Comment: @chrylis my question is not about Java Syntax. It is about the VBA. I don't understand that  how "i" variable used after the loop in VBA and how can I convert to Java?

Answer (score 1):

Declare i right before for loop.  Since this is a Java question, the for loop is dramatically different in this language and you have to think about the scope.

```
int i;
for (i = 1; i < M-1; i++) 
{
}
//i retains its value here
```

The reason is in VBA i remains in scope as soon as it's initialized. Where in a Java for loop, that variable is destroyed upon completion, unless it was declared prior.  VB has gave me headaches because of that as i is reused frequently in code.